# How to use complex-number of kairosdb from REST

Tags: opentsdb, kairosdb

I am checking if I can use kairosdb for my project. I was checking out the REST api's and I have a use case where I need to save both my device state and status (state tells if device is on or off and status tells if my device is occupied or empty)

```
kairosdb version: 1.1.1


I came across this link https://kairosdb.github.io/docs/build/html/restapi/AddDataPoints.html
but when I try to post data from REST client I am getting the error 400 BAD Request error. The error is 

{"errors":["Unregistered data point type 'complex-number'"]}

My request I am posting is ,
 {
      "name": "device_data",
      "type": "complex-number",
      "datapoints": [
          [
              1470897496,
              {
                  "state": 0,
                  "status": "empty"
              }
          ]
      ],
      "tags": {
          "device_id": "abc123"
      }
  }

In tried doing the same in Java as specified in  https://kairosdb.github.io/docs/build/html/kairosdevelopment/CustomData.html
```

I get the same error i
    Please let me know how to use complex-numbers or custom data types from REST

Answer (score 3):

Recently, I figured out how to use this.

Using the example from the official document of KairosDB.

1. create 2 files called `ComplexDataPoint.java` and `ComplexDataPointFactory.java` and then paste the code provided by the tutorial on the doc: https://kairosdb.github.io/docs/build/html/kairosdevelopment/CustomData.html#example-for-creating-custom-types
2. download the KairosDB source, then extract the `.zip` file.
3. paste the 2 files in `/KAIROSDB_DOWNLOADED_SOURCE/src/main/java/org/kairosdb/core/datapoints/`
4. configure the `CoreModule.java` at `/KAIROSDB_DOWNLOADED_SOURCE/src/main/java/org/kairosdb/core/`, add the following line in the function `protected void configure()`:

   ```
   bind(ComplexDataPointFactory.class).in(Singleton.class);
   ```
5. open terminal, cd to `KAIROSDB_DOWNLOADED_SOURCE/`, then follow the instruction in the file **how_to_build.txt**
6. when complete, it will create a folder called **build**, the compiled kairosdb jar file is located in `KAIROSDB_DOWNLOADED_SOURCE/build/jar`
7. in your kairosdb installation folder, backup the `kairosdb-X.X.X.jar` file in **YOUR_KAIROSDB_INSTALLATION/lib**

   ```
   mv kairosdb-X.X.X.jar kairosdb-X.X.X.jar.backup
   ```
8. `mv` the newly compiled jar file to **YOUR_KAIROSDB_INSTALLATION/lib**
9. modify the configuration file by adding the following line:

   ```
   kairosdb.datapoints.factory.complex=org.kairosdb.core.datapoints.ComplexDataPointFactory
   ```
10. restart your kairosdb

For your query, since the registered name is `kairosdb.datapoints.factory.complex`, replace `complex-number` with `complex` in your query string.

Hope this will help you! I am now having a problem to plot the complex data. I am still figuring out...